# What does the word "Mevoar" mean in "NaKh Mevoar"?

Tags: hebrew, tanach

I often see books titled "NaKh Mevoar" or "Rashi Mevoar". What does the word "Mevoar" mean?

Comment: This appears to be off-topic as per the [Help Center](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). You may consider supporting the Hebrew Language Area51 proposal as mentioned [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/tags/hebrew/info).

Comment: It might be on topic. Are you asking specifically in the contexts of titles of books?

Comment: I've seen this term translated as "illustrated". It's not the best translation, because in English, this word really means "explained by using examples, charts or pictures" (Google). Some "mevo'ar" books do this, but, they are few.

Answer (score 2):

מבואר: "Made clear" or "explained." Root is bet-aleph-raish.

Deuteronomy 1:5 said Moses began באר את-התורה "be'er et haTorah" -- "[to explain the law](http://bible.ort.org/books/pentd2.asp?ACTION=displaypage&BOOK=5&CHAPTER=1)."  (JPS has "to expound", same idea.)

Deuteronomy 27:8 says to write the Torah on some stones "ba'er heiteiv." Heiteiv means "very well." It's translated as: "[a clear script](http://bible.ort.org/books/pentd2.asp?ACTION=displaypage&BOOK=5&CHAPTER=27#C4351)" (Kaplan), or "[very plainly](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0527.htm)" (JPS).